# Why is NTFS volume not valid? The device '/dev/sdd1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I mounted my HDD a hundred times before, but now I got this

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/mojmaunt/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdd1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
```

MBR is 86.
Should I change it?

This is how sdd looks

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 698,6 GiB, 750121910272 bytes, 1465081856 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3ef4e255

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 1465081855 1465079808 698,6G 86 NTFS volume set

sudo fsck -t ntfs /dev/sdd1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1

sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd1
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, this is not Windows related(comments issue).

Comment: Maybe just a dirty unmount. Have you tried to check it vi `fsck -t ntfs /dev/sdd1` and possibly clean the drity bit (or other errors) with `ntfsfix /dev/sdd1` first? Tell us the output. (might actually be the same program in some instances ...)

Comment: Did you mount in Windows & it set hibernation (fast start up) flag? Then Linux will not mount it. Or it may just need chkdsk from Windows to repair it. Linux tools can only do minor repairs and usually just turn on the chkdsk needed flag so Windows runs chkdsk on reboot. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Note that the partition type is shown as NTFS **volume set** rather than a simple NTFS filesystem. Did someone accidentally convert the disk to Windows Dynamic Disk (I.e. the Windows equivalent for Linux LVM) or something?